# GL(2,2) and Diagonal subgroup

Tags: group-theory

Take $GL(2,2)$ and $D_2$ which is the trivial subgroup has only the identity element in it. So $D_2$ is the diagonal subgroup. So $N_{GL(2,2)}D_2$ should be the monomial matrices which consist of two matrices, one the identity and one the identity with columns swapped. However, I find the normalizer is the whole GL(2,2)! Why it doesn't add up here? Is it because the field is not big enough?

Comment: The normalizer of the trivial subgroup is always the whole group. Everything commutes with the identity element.

Comment: Hi! Yes. But according to this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_permutation_matrix   it should also be the monomial matrices, right? but not all elements in GL(2,2) is a monomial matrix, if I am correct...

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I'm following. $GL(2,2)$ is the group of invertible $2 \times 2$ matrices with entries from $\{0,1\}$, correct? And what is $D_2$?

Comment: Yes, correct. $D_2$ should be the group of diagonal matrices

Comment: Right. So in $GL(2,2)$, there is only one diagonal matrix, which is the identity matrix. There are no other diagonal matrices. So $D_2$ is trivial. The normalizer of $D_2$ must then be everything. I don't think you need to think about monomial matrices here. (In $GL(2,2)$, the entries of the matrix can only be $0$ and $1$, so the generalization in the link you provided doesn't do anything).